# LCG create method to set a subset of all properties in class (reflection substitute; c#)

Tags: c#, reflection, code-generation, il, lcg

Scenario: I have this class

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

User has the ability to only select for example `FirstName` and `Age`.

Currently I am using reflection but I have been told that reflection hurts performance among other things.

```
public static class Helper<T>GetObject(List<string> fieldsToSet, Dictionary<string, string> values)
{
    var returnObject = new T();

    foreach (string field in fieldsToSet)
    {
        var property = returnObject.GetType().GetProperty(field);
        property.SetValue(returnObject, values[field], null);
    }        

    return returnObject;
}
```

Can anyone show me an example of how to do this (setting only a subset of all the fields in a class) using lightweight code generation?

Comment: @usr LINQ expressions are slow as well but they are way more elegant, one can also use something like https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.

Comment: @Aybe the way to go is create an expression once, compile it and store a delegate to the compiled code.

Comment: @usr Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try in my application.